# Unable to install AppStore version directly to mobile device when using an iOS App Extension

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-app-extension

At our company the process we execute normally is:

- fix/implement
- test ad-hoc version
- create AppStore package
- test that AppStore package by installing it directly through iTunes.
- submit version to AppStore.

The reason why we need to test also the AppStore version is because some payment services wouldn't work if we didn't. So we need a real environment.

Previously to the inclusion of the iOS App Extension (sharing) we could do this process without issues, but now after doing the same process we can't do it anymore.

We can;

- test the ad-hoc version by signing the app extension as ad-hoc.
- create and submit the app store package.

However we can't install the app store version anymore, the error mentions that there are issues with the signature, more precisely:

```
(Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?.

Comment: Check profile used to sign application in iTunes store, may be you need to permit access to some resources or services there.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be able to install the app store version on a physical device and run it.

It can work in certain scenarios (like if you had previously installed development builds on there and there was a valid development build on the device when you try to run the app store build).  Maybe the device has the old app provisioning profile (which would not have the app extensions entitlement).  The new one that is embedded with the app (and has the appropriate entitlements) is an App Store provisioning profile and is not valid for running directly on the device.

I would make a new build config in your project that is a copy of the Release config, except for **only the code signing settings**.  That would allow you to run a build that will be exactly the production App Store build, except for the code signing settings.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense, the reason why we could install the app before was because of having it previously installed. However we did the same thing with the extension, but didn't work. The problem is, people here wants to test _exactly_ the same version we are submiting to the appstore, in our devices. We use TeamCity, create an appstore package, and then use that through iTunes or iFunBox to install it manually. Except this time we can't with the app extension.

Comment: I don't know why iOS would handle profile caching differently for extensions than the app.  That's the odd part. You could re-sign the app with your ad hoc profile / cert.  That would allow the binary to be exactly the same, but the embedded profile / signing would be the only thing that is different.  That would basically give you what you had before, since the app you were testing before was not using the app store profile.

Comment: You make a good point, the installed "appstore" build was actually using the ad-hoc profile anyway.